# Finding duplicates across multiple columns repeated in more than certain number of columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a .CSV file containing multiple columns and more than hundred rows with some shared elements(duplicates) across different columns. 
could anybody suggest me a code in R which finds shared elements that are repeated **in more than certain number of columns**?

[image]

For instance I want to find elements which are repeated in more than 3 columns in the above table, and I expect it to return c3,a1 and f1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With subtle changes to akrun code, I guess I found out this is what I wanted:

`names(table(unlist(d1)))[table(unlist(d1))>=3]`

Answer (score 0):

We could do this by getting the frequency of elements after `unlist`ing, do the column sums, `sort` and get the `names` of the highest frequency

```
names(tail(sort(colSums(table(c(col(d1)), unlist(d1)))),3))
#[1] "a1" "c3" "f1"
```

#### data

```
d1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a1", "b2", "f1", "d1"), col2 = c("c3", 
"a1", "g1", "f1"), col3 = c("d3", "c3", "h1", "f1"), col4 = c("c3", 
"a1", "n1", "f1")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank U for Ur answer. The problem with the code is that, it doesn’t return elements which are repeated in more than x number of columns but the x top repeated elements across columns. For instance, when U put 4 in the code which means elements that are repeated in 4 or more columns, U expect to get only f1 but it returns "n1" "a1" "c3" “f1" , which are the 4 mostly repeated elements. This is also true for other numbers of x.